# Converting lines of text to a matrix in R

Tags: r, string

I have a file read by readLines in R. Between index sndx and endx is a table of space separated numbers. I would like to convert these to a matrix. For example a toy example file would be:

```
======
3 5   # this is how I know sndx and endx
Some text
1  123.  456. 789.
2  345.  678. 123.
3  235.  123. 345.
More text
======
```

The desired output would be the matrix:

```
1  123.  456. 789.
2  345.  678. 123.
3  235.  123. 345.
```

Is there a way to extract the numerical lines in this way?

Comment: Can you `dput` the toy R object created by `readLines`?

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
"Some text
endx
1  123.  456. 789.
2  345.  678. 123.
3  235.  123. 345.
sndx
More text"
```

Using `strsplit`:

```
char_vec <- trimws(readClipboard())    

# Need the string after 'endx'
str_start <- grep('endx', char_vec)+1

# And the string before 'sndx'
str_end <- grep('sndx', char_vec)-1

# The output here is a matrix but we need the transpose of the output  
t(sapply(str_start:str_end, function(z){
  u <- char_vec[z]
  ret <- strsplit(x = gsub('\\.', "", u), split = '[[:space:]]{1,5}')[[1]]
  return(ret)
}))
```

Output:

```
> t(sapply(str_start:str_end, function(z){
+   u <- char_vec[z]
+   ret <- strsplit(x = gsub('\\.', "", u), split = '[[:space:]]{1,5}')[[1]]
+   return(ret)
+ }))
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
[1,] "1"  "123" "456" "789"
[2,] "2"  "345" "678" "123"
[3,] "3"  "235" "123" "345"
```